# PowerShell outtput to HTML

Tags: powershell

Using the following and would like to know how to output the results to HTML file

```
$Start = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)
$Computername = gc C:\Temp\List.txt 
$Events = gc C:\Temp\ErrorCodes.txt

Get-EventLog -AsString -ComputerName $Computername |
ForEach-Object {
# write status info
Write-Progress -Activity "Checking Eventlogs on \\$ComputerName" -Status $_

# get event entries and add the name of the log this came from
Get-EventLog -LogName $_ -EntryType Error, Warning -After $Start -ComputerName $ComputerName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
  Add-Member NoteProperty EventLog $_ -PassThru | Where-Object {$Events -contains $_.eventid}

} |
# select the properties for the report
Select-Object EventLog, EventID, TimeGenerated, EntryType, Source, Message
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get it to print with pretty colors. You can tinker around with it and change whatever you want.

```
$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "BODY{background-color:peachpuff;}"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color:black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:thistle}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:palegoldenrod}"
$a = $a + "</style>"

$Variable = get-what_I_want
$Variable2 = get-what_I_want
$VariableHTML = $Variable | ConvertTo-HTML -head $a -body "<H2>Title I want</H2>"
$Variable2HTML = $Variable2 | ConvertTo-HTML -head $a -body "<H1>Header One</H1> <H2>Header Two</H2> <H3>Header Three</H3> <p>Paragraph<p/>"
$VariableHTML > C:\PoSH\My_Exported_HTML.html
```

I added a second variable. As you can see, you can add different levels of headers and a Paragraph. I found this helpful for single line items or if you want a better description.

Answer (score 1):

If I would say: `ConvertTo-Html` is what you need, than probably that would be enough to add a comment.

Instead I will say: before asking questions outside PowerShell, ask them inside PowerShell first.

```
Get-Help *html*
```